# Magento 2.2.10 and PHP 7.3

Tags: php, magento, magento2

Magento 2.2.10 has patches available for PHP 7.2 support (https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html#database).

However, PHP 7.2 is only supported until the end of the year (https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php).

Is there a sense within the Mangento community that additional patches will be made available to support PHP 7.3 and greater?

Comment: The answer is yes. Unfortunately, there are still old clients that have Magento 2.1 or even Magento 1 installations on their stores, and I can see there are patches for M1 with php 7.2 and 7.3. Which means the magento community versions are still releasing patches for all versions of Magento to support the clients that are still using them.

Comment: This would make sense, and is something I would expect, but not assume. Are there any resources or online references that outline specific patches?

Comment: Just go to Magento 2 Official Downloads site and look for the patches, they are there and explain on which version are applying to